# HTML/JQUERY form select options specify starting point

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am using a jquery script to create some custom style select boxes on form, jquery script here: http://www.bulgaria-web-developers.com/projects/javascript/selectbox/. (This question doesn't really relate to the jquery script, but thought I should include it.)

I have a select (dropdown) option on a form which has heights from 1 foot to 6 foot. By default the first option is 1 foot, but I would like it to start at around 5 foot, as this is a more common option. I still want to maintain the ability to scroll up and down through the options in order from smallest to highest.

'selected' does not produce the result I am looking for. Does anyone know how get this to work?

Thanks

---

As requested a bit more info, here is an example of the dropdown:

```
<select name="height">
<option value="1 1">1ft 1 in</option>
<option value="1 2">1ft 2 in</option>
<option value="1 3">1ft 3 in</option>
<option value="1 4">1ft 4 in</option>
<option value="1 5">1ft 5 in</option>
<option value="1 6">1ft 6 in</option>
<option value="1 7">1ft 7 in</option>
<option value="1 8">1ft 8 in</option>
<option value="1 9">1ft 9 in</option>
...
</select>
```

This list goes on, but when user come to the list they have to scroll all the way to their height, so I would like to make the starting point around 5ft 0in so that users can scroll up or down where they need to.

Comment: Need a bit more than this dude?

Comment: what do you mean by 5 foot and 6 foot ?

Comment: i cant understand your question, be more specific please

Answer (score 1):

Selected works as expected for me using the script

```
<option value="1">1 ft</option>
<option value="2">2 ft</option>
<option value="3">3 ft</option>
<option value="4">4 ft</option>
<option value="5" selected>5 ft</option>
<option value="6">6 ft</option>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. This does set 5ft as the main option, but on clicking to view the dropdown starts at 1ft.